# I think OSX-gcc-installer broke some things and I'm not sure what to do

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, macos, gcc

Long story short is I foolishly installed OSX-gcc-installer about a month ago and at first it prevented me, I believe, from installing Ruby gems on my machine. With the help of someone I did get this one issue fixed. Going through other the other posts on this website I was not able to find the solution that I'm looking for, so I decided to post here.

When I run `brew doctor` I get the following:

```
albys-mbp:folder alby$ brew doctor
Please note that these warnings are just used to help the Homebrew maintainers
with debugging if you file an issue. If everything you use Homebrew for is
working fine: please don't worry and just ignore them. Thanks!

Warning: You have an outdated version of /usr/bin/install_name_tool installed.
This will cause binary package installations to fail.
This can happen if you install osx-gcc-installer or RailsInstaller.
To restore it, you must reinstall OS X or restore the binary from
the OS packages.

Warning: Broken symlinks were found. Remove them with `brew prune`:
  /usr/local/bin/aclocal
  /usr/local/bin/aclocal-1.14
  /usr/local/bin/autoconf
  /usr/local/bin/autoheader
  /usr/local/bin/autom4te
  /usr/local/bin/automake
  /usr/local/bin/automake-1.14
  /usr/local/bin/autoreconf
  /usr/local/bin/autoscan
  /usr/local/bin/autoupdate
  /usr/local/bin/cscope
  /usr/local/bin/erb
  /usr/local/bin/gem
  /usr/local/bin/glibtool
  /usr/local/bin/glibtoolize
  /usr/local/bin/gpg-error
  /usr/local/bin/gpg-error-config
  /usr/local/bin/ifnames
  /usr/local/bin/irb
  /usr/local/bin/ksba-config
  /usr/local/bin/ocs
  /usr/local/bin/pkg-config
  /usr/local/bin/rake
  /usr/local/bin/rdoc
  /usr/local/bin/ri
  /usr/local/bin/ruby
  /usr/local/bin/testrb
  /usr/local/include/gpg-error.h
  /usr/local/include/ksba.h
  /usr/local/include/libltdl
  /usr/local/include/ltdl.h
  /usr/local/include/ruby-2.1.0
  /usr/local/include/yaml.h
  /usr/local/lib/libgpg-error.0.dylib
  /usr/local/lib/libgpg-error.dylib
  /usr/local/lib/libksba.8.dylib
  /usr/local/lib/libksba.dylib
  /usr/local/lib/libltdl.7.dylib
  /usr/local/lib/libltdl.a
  /usr/local/lib/libltdl.dylib
  /usr/local/lib/libruby.2.1.0-static.a
  /usr/local/lib/libruby.2.1.0.dylib
  /usr/local/lib/libruby.2.1.dylib
  /usr/local/lib/libruby.dylib
  /usr/local/lib/libyaml-0.2.dylib
  /usr/local/lib/libyaml.a
  /usr/local/lib/libyaml.dylib
  /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/ruby-2.1.pc
  /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/yaml-0.1.pc
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems
  /usr/local/share/aclocal/README
  /usr/local/share/aclocal/argz.m4
  /usr/local/share/aclocal/dirlist
  /usr/local/share/aclocal/gpg-error.m4
  /usr/local/share/aclocal/ksba.m4
  /usr/local/share/aclocal/libtool.m4
  /usr/local/share/aclocal/ltdl.m4
  /usr/local/share/aclocal/ltoptions.m4
  /usr/local/share/aclocal/ltsugar.m4
  /usr/local/share/aclocal/ltversion.m4
  /usr/local/share/aclocal/lt~obsolete.m4
  /usr/local/share/aclocal/pkg.m4
  /usr/local/share/aclocal-1.14
  /usr/local/share/autoconf
  /usr/local/share/automake-1.14
  /usr/local/share/common-lisp
  /usr/local/share/doc/automake
  /usr/local/share/doc/pkg-config/pkg-config-guide.html
  /usr/local/share/emacs
  /usr/local/share/info/gpgrt.info
  /usr/local/share/info/ksba.info
  /usr/local/share/info/libtool.info
  /usr/local/share/info/libtool.info-1
  /usr/local/share/info/libtool.info-2
  /usr/local/share/libtool
  /usr/local/share/man/man1/aclocal-1.14.1
  /usr/local/share/man/man1/aclocal.1
  /usr/local/share/man/man1/autoconf.1
  /usr/local/share/man/man1/autoheader.1
  /usr/local/share/man/man1/autom4te.1
  /usr/local/share/man/man1/automake-1.14.1
  /usr/local/share/man/man1/automake.1
  /usr/local/share/man/man1/autoreconf.1
  /usr/local/share/man/man1/autoscan.1
  /usr/local/share/man/man1/autoupdate.1
  /usr/local/share/man/man1/config.guess.1
  /usr/local/share/man/man1/config.sub.1
  /usr/local/share/man/man1/cscope.1
  /usr/local/share/man/man1/erb.1
  /usr/local/share/man/man1/glibtool.1
  /usr/local/share/man/man1/glibtoolize.1
  /usr/local/share/man/man1/gpg-error-config.1
  /usr/local/share/man/man1/ifnames.1
  /usr/local/share/man/man1/irb.1
  /usr/local/share/man/man1/pkg-config.1
  /usr/local/share/man/man1/rake.1
  /usr/local/share/man/man1/ri.1
  /usr/local/share/man/man1/ruby.1
  /usr/local/Library/LinkedKegs/autoconf
  /usr/local/Library/LinkedKegs/automake
  /usr/local/Library/LinkedKegs/cscope
  /usr/local/Library/LinkedKegs/libgpg-error
  /usr/local/Library/LinkedKegs/libksba
  /usr/local/Library/LinkedKegs/libtool
  /usr/local/Library/LinkedKegs/libyaml
  /usr/local/Library/LinkedKegs/pkg-config
  /usr/local/Library/LinkedKegs/ruby

Warning: You seem to have osx-gcc-installer installed.
Homebrew doesn't support osx-gcc-installer. It causes many builds to fail and
is an unlicensed distribution of really old Xcode files.
Please run `xcode-select --install` to install the CLT.

Warning: Some installed formula are missing dependencies.
You should `brew install` the missing dependencies:

    brew install openssl

Run `brew missing` for more details.
alby-mbp:folder alby$
```

As you can also see above, I am missing `openssl`. This is because I uninstalled it and attempted to reinstall it thinking that this would help, but I was not able to reinstall. Here is what I get when I try to do `brew install openssl`:

```
albys-mbp:folder alby$ brew install openssl
Warning: You seem to have osx-gcc-installer installed.
Homebrew doesn't support osx-gcc-installer. It causes many builds to fail and
is an unlicensed distribution of really old Xcode files.
Please run `xcode-select --install` to install the CLT.
Warning: You have an outdated version of /usr/bin/install_name_tool installed.
This will cause binary package installations to fail.
This can happen if you install osx-gcc-installer or RailsInstaller.
To restore it, you must reinstall OS X or restore the binary from
the OS packages.
==> Downloading https://downloads.sf.net/project/machomebrew/Bottles/openssl-1.0.1j_1.mavericks.bottle.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/openssl-1.0.1j_1.mavericks.bottle.tar.gz
Error: SHA1 mismatch
Expected: 65e125a4777eb6dfb63f01a18f724246123dd79e
Actual: eac5e2d21af64224fc533ebb793b99a2aea434c7
Archive: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/openssl-1.0.1j_1.mavericks.bottle.tar.gz
To retry an incomplete download, remove the file above.
Warning: Bottle installation failed: building from source.
==> Installing openssl dependency: makedepend
==> Downloading https://downloads.sf.net/project/machomebrew/Bottles/makedepend-1.0.5.mavericks.bottle.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/makedepend-1.0.5.mavericks.bottle.tar.gz
Error: SHA1 mismatch
Expected: 83db1daee01e4eb752c711934eb88850b3ee70d6
Actual: eac5e2d21af64224fc533ebb793b99a2aea434c7
Archive: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/makedepend-1.0.5.mavericks.bottle.tar.gz
To retry an incomplete download, remove the file above.
Warning: Bottle installation failed: building from source.
Error: /usr/local/opt/pkg-config not present or broken
Please reinstall pkg-config. Sorry :(
albys-mbp:folder alby$
```

Another issue is that when I try and run `mysql` in bash, I get the following:

```
albys-mbp:folder alby$ mysql
dyld: Library not loaded: @@HOMEBREW_PREFIX@@/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/mysql
  Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap: 5
albys-mbp:folder alby$
```

I am mostly new to programming and am not sure where to begin to solve this issue. I was able to backup my HD to an external HD, but this is after installing the gcc-installer which overwrote my Command Line Tools. So even if I were to do a reinstall, would that even work? I've never had to reinstall my OS X before; would I be able to pick and choose files from the external HD or is it all restored?

Also, I have OS X 10.9.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you find a fix for this? I'm running into the same problem.

Comment: Sorry for the late response! Unfortunately I had to backup my HD and completely reinstall the OS :(

Comment: That sucks. I found a way for others to avoid that, and I uploaded the necessary OSX Mavericks files to a torrent as well: http://magnemg.tumblr.com/post/113251602430/how-to-completely-uninstall-osx-gcc-installer